# NextAuth Documentation refers to a version that doesnt exist?

Tags: next-auth

I am trying to implement the following:

https://next-auth.js.org/tutorials/securing-pages-and-api-routes#nextjs-middleware

I want to list all my secure pages in the `const config` object.  However on that page it references that 'since NextAuth 4.2....` Well the [npmjs page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-auth?activeTab=versions) only shows up to v4.17 - Is this why I can't get it to work? Why is it documenting something that we cannot even use yet?